# fade background image of div, and text within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using jQuery, I'd like to cycle through 3 different background-images and 3 sets of text within "box", fading to the next every 6 seconds.

CSS:

```
.box {
background: url(/filepath/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<h1>Headline</h1>
<h2>Sub-text</h2>
</div>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well the *best* way is fairly subjective, but you can use `setInterval` and set up 3 style rules that have the different bg images and text.  You may want to preload the iamges.

```
.boxy {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.box1 {
    background-image: url(/filepath/to/image1.jpg);
    opacity: .8;
}
/* other boxes omitted for brevity */
```

Then you can do something akin to:

```
var boxen = [3, 1, 2];
setInterval(function () {
    boxen.push(boxen.shift());
    $(".box").removeClass(boxen.map(function (elem) { return "box" + elem; })
        .addClass("box" + boxen[0]);
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't fade between background images of the same element.  My suggestion would be to insert three (or however many you want, really) images, positioned absolutely on top of each other and then fade between those.

You can also do the same for the text elements you'd like to fade through, or you could construct a series of divs containing any combination of the both.

Actually, there's an almost infinite number of approaches you could take to achieve the effect you're describing, but trying to fade the background-image just ain't one of them.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="slide bg1">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="slide bg2">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="slide bg3">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div> <!-- END .box -->
```

Style...

```
.box {
    position: relative; /* Set to relative to keep the containing .slide divs, ahem, relative */
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.bg1 { /* There are more elegant ways of targeting the individual slides, I'm just being lazy... */
    background-image: src('/dir/img.jpg');
}
.bg2{}
.bg3{} /* Etc, etc... */
```

Fading between the child divs will not only allow you to change the appearance of the background-image, but anything else you might want to fade (or anything else for that matter).

As for the javascript, there are a thousand and one resources out there that covers exactly this, so I'll defer to them (Google it!).

Comment: This makes sense - I've set it up so that I have "box1", "box2" and "box3".
They're stacked up on top of each other perfectly, and I've done a quick search on Google to find a piece of code that will auto fade between all 3 then loop, but I haven't found anything appropriate yet that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery function setInterval() for 6 second interval. Fadding effect and iteration between 3 elements is then easy to implement...

```
var loop = 1;
var id = setInterval(function() {

if(loop === 3)
{
    loop = 1; //reset loop back
   //clearInterval(id); cancel interval
}
alert(" loop: "+loop);
//TODO: fadding + changing text here maybe in separate function...

loop++;

}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to consider to use some jQuery slider plugin like
[Awkward Showcase](http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/) or [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for example